# QT calling functions in different sources

Tags: c++, qt, function, public

In my project I've created multiple gui pages. In a secondary source (secondary.cpp) I want to call a function that declared in my `mainwindow.cpp`. I'm not really sure how to do this.

I've tried to declare the function at public section like:

```
QString format (QString number);
```

And definition in the `mainwindow.cpp` like:

```
QString MainWindow::format(QString number) 
{
   ...
}
```

Then i include `#include "mainwindow.h"` in my secondary source (`secondary.cpp`) and calling the function with `lower = format(upper);` but I'm getting an error message:

> format was not declared in this scope.

I've also tried calling it by

```
lower = MainWindow::format(upper);
```

which gives me the error message

> Cannot call member function QString MainWindown::format(Qstring)
>   without object.

Finaly I also tried to make a class in my `mainwindow.h`

```
class test : public QString
{
public:
     QString format (QString number);
};
```

With `QString test::format(QString number)` in my `mainwindow.cpp` calling the function by `lower = test::format(upper);`
this gives me the error:

> Cannot call member function QString MainWindown::format(QString)
>   without object.

I'm not convinced that I need to create a new class, but I thought I'd try anyway.

Comment: Please read an introduction about object-oriented programming in C++. You should either make the method `static`, or define it as a regular function outside the `MainWindow` class.

Comment: Indeed, this is not at all related to QT, but is more one of the basics of OO programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create object of `MainWindow` class, then call function:

```
MainWindow *w = new MainWindow;
QString lower = w->format(upper);
```

Or another solution is static function of class. This way you have no needed create object of class and can call method by name like this:

```
QString lower = MainWindow::format(upper);
```

Of course you need to include your `#include "mainwindow.h"` header.

But you should know that `MainWindow` class is not the best place storing function for formation string, you can use [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) class function like [`QString::toUpper()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUpper) or [`QString::toLower()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLower) or create your own class for formating:

```
class myFormatingStringClass {
     QString toLower(QString str);
     static QStrin toUpper(QString str);
}
```

As i said above this way you will need to create object of `myFormatingStringClass` for using `myFormatingStringClass::toLower()` function or using static method:

```
QString upper = QString("Hello World");
myFormatingStringClass formating;
QString lower = formatin.toLower(upper);                // Using class method of existing object
QString upper = myFormatingStringClass::toUpper(lower); // Using static method
```

Comment: Hi, cheers for the answer, but I was wondering won't I also require : public QString and public: to be in my main header file? also would this be the best method to accesses strings created in the mainwindow from other sources?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `test::format(...)` to call a non-static member function.

It must be bound to an object (an instance of your `class`). For example, you can do this :

```
test testObject;
QString formattedString = testObject.format(strToFormat);
```

Comment: Cheers your method works great, but I was wondering if you had an opinion about whose solutions is best suited to answering my problem, yours or  t3ft3l--i's?

Comment: @JonCO please, don't use `MainWindow` class for working with strings, it is not `MainWindow` main goal and it is bad-smells style.

Comment: If you want my real opinion, you should not put this function inside a class. A namespace containing a standalone function is a perfect choice.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback